# I want to remove light mode and create a toggle button for night mode

Tags: jquery

I want to make a single toggle button for night mode, instead of the two I have now.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nightMode').click(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('LightMode');
    $('body').addClass('nightMode');
  });
  
  $('#LightMode').click(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('nightMode');
    $('body').addClass('LightMode');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.nightMode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.LightMode {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.nightbtn {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.lightbtn {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.firstParagraph {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gold;
}

.secondParagraph {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gold;
}

.doubleSection {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="LightMode" class="lightbtn"> Light Mode</button>
<button id="nightMode" class="nightbtn">Dark Mode</button>

<h1>Dark Mode is better than Day Light Mode</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<div class="doubleSection">
  <p class="firstParagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque iure soluta nihil recusandae distinctio, molestias eius provident dicta? Culpa aliquid velit pariatur repellat dolorem. Dolorem iure, magni expedita quis ex.</p>
  <p class="secondParagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque iure soluta nihil recusandae distinctio, molestias eius provident dicta? Culpa aliquid velit pariatur repellat dolorem. Dolorem iure, magni expedita quis ex.</p>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<footer>
  @Free to use
</footer>
```

https://codepen.io/naveen-jayawardana/pen/oNXoNBZ

Comment: https://codepen.io/naveen-jayawardana/pen/oNXoNBZ

Comment: i want to create one button for day and night

Comment: for example if you click the button night mode is on, and you click again night mode is off

Comment: I've edited your question to include all relevant details, such as the complete code example and the description of your goal. Please ensure this is included from the start in future questions.

Comment: Thanks, bro..now I can forward with my project.

Comment: can you explatin what is meaning of  this jQuery($ =>

Comment: It's a standard jQuery document.ready handler, but using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to create one button for toggling day and night

In this case put the 'light' classes on the `body` by default. Then assign a single handler to a button instance which calls `toggleClass()` to set the 'night' class on the `body`, like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#toggle').on('click', function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('nightMode');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.nightMode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.firstParagraph {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gold;
}

.secondParagraph {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gold;
}

.doubleSection {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">Toggle Mode</button>

<h1>Dark Mode is better than Day Light Mode</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<div class="doubleSection">
  <p class="firstParagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque iure soluta nihil recusandae distinctio, molestias eius provident dicta? Culpa aliquid velit pariatur repellat dolorem. Dolorem iure, magni expedita quis ex.</p>

  <p class="secondParagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque iure soluta nihil recusandae distinctio, molestias eius provident dicta? Culpa aliquid velit pariatur repellat dolorem. Dolorem iure, magni expedita quis ex.</p>
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<footer>
  @Free to use
</footer>
```